# Why is the error "Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead"?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests-html

I'm running the code provided by @Dan-Dev in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63541958/7357673).

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://www.thefreedictionary.com/love'
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
lang_bar = r.html.find('#LangBar', first=True)
print(lang_bar.html)
```

and the result is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ec1d9137b197> in <module>
      8 
      9 resp = session.get(url, headers = headers)
---> 10 resp.html.render()
     11 
     12 soup = bs(resp.html.html, "lxml")

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py in render(self, retries, script, wait, scrolldown, sleep, reload, timeout, keep_page)
    584         """
    585 
--> 586         self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
    587         content = None
    588 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py in browser(self)
    727             self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    728             if self.loop.is_running():
--> 729                 raise RuntimeError("Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.")
    730             self._browser = self.loop.run_until_complete(super().browser)
    731         return self._browser

RuntimeError: Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.
```

Clearly, the code runs fine in Dan-Dev's computer. Could you please explain why my laptop returns an error `Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead`?

Comment: Can you post details of your environment OS Python version etc? Are you using Jupyter Notebook? Have you tried using AsyncHTMLSession instead of HTMLSession?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this:

```py
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get("URL")

html_str = r.text
```

Comment: Where does `url_template` come from? No import in your original answer.

Comment: I was usiing a url template to build url dynamically. This is not important here so I have just replaced this by a random url.

Answer (score 4):

Use `arender()` instead of `render()` or set the script as async

Answer (score 2):

You can save these codes in a source file, such as 'src.py'. Then open an **Anaconda Prompt** (assuming you are using this) and run this command (assure you are in the folder containing the 'src.py' file)

```
python src.py
```

This solution has worked for me. You should not run the source file in Spyder IDE or Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

This code may works because it needs some periods time to render the object.

```py
r.html.arender(timeout=0,sleep=20)
```

Comment: Please add a citation for this.